# Have multiple filters working on an item in isotope plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-isotope

Goal - The user should be able to select a single option or multiple options. Based on that selection the div having the right classes should come up the stack.

The div which do not have the right classes should go down the stack and have a class .notpicked.

With div's having single class works well reference: http://jsfiddle.net/GwBa8/56/

However I am not sure how can I get over having multiple classes for each item ? I am guessing the selection is an issue here ?

```
$container.isotope({
itemSelector: '.item',
// filter red items first

});
```

You an see the full code for multiple options here:

**http://jsfiddle.net/vishalkhialani/MCv7S/**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a bit closer using [$.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

```
$checked = $(checked);
$unchecked = $(unchecked).not($checked); // <== keeps all the checked stuff out of your not checked list
```

This will keep things at the front of the list, in the order they were checked. I believe this is what you are asking for, although it may not be what you end up wanting :)

[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidcl64/MCv7S/3/)

To me the UX is a bit of though as items with multiple categories checked don't push their way to the top of the list.

---

Heres a different version that uses sortData to help reorder the items.  It uses the number of matching categories to bump things up in the list.

It doesn't remember the order of category selection though but thought I'd post as it may spur some other ideas.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidcl64/MCv7S/6/)

Key changes:

Added a matchCount method that returns -1*numberOfMatches.  This allows you to use the default ascending sort mode of Isotope and keeps Isotope from reversing the order of elements.

```
getSortData: {
    matchCount: function ( $elem ) {
        var count = 0;
        $checkboxes.filter(':checked').each(function () {
            if($elem.hasClass(this.name)) {
                // Using a negative count here so we can use sort ascending
                // Keeps things in a better order as isotope animates the changes
                count--;
            }
        });
        return count;
    }
}
```

On each checkbox change, replaced the existing add/remove items with:

```
$container.isotope( 'updateSortData', $('.item'));

// Sort decending seems to simply reverse the sort so items reverse themselves
$container.isotope({ sortBy: 'matchCount'});//, sortAscending: false });
```

Update: added simple `&&` logic to exclude items without **ALL** selected categories in `.unpicked`:

[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidcl64/MCv7S/8/)

Change to matchCount:

```
// Simple && check of all categories.  
//
// Item must have all categories to be considered checked.
if((-count) && checkedItems.length === (-count)) {
    $elem.removeClass('notpicked');
} else {
    $elem.addClass('notpicked');
}
```

Comment: the demo for sorting is working well however where can I add and remove class .notpicked ? if the user selects 'building1 and studio'. I want to assign '2bedroom building1' and '3bedroom building1' as .notpicked even thought building1 has been checked.

Comment: @VishalKhialani - Added logic to set as 'unpicked' any items that don't match ALL categories